# AVX - storing __256 vector back to the memory (void**) in C,

Tags: c, vector, void-pointers, memory-alignment, avx

I have the following code extract written in C,

```
  double* res;
  posix_memalign((void **)&res, 32, sizeof(double)*4);

  __m256 ymm0, ymm1, ymm2, ymm3;

  ymm0 = _mm256_load_pd(vector_a);
  ymm1 = _mm256_load_pd(vector_b);

  ymm2 = _mm256_mul_pd(ymm1, ymm2); 

  ymm3 = _mm256_store_pd((double*)res, ymm3); <--- problem line,
```

When I compile, I get the following error message,

```
 error: assigning to '__m256' from incompatible type 'void'
    ymm3 = _mm256_store_pd((double*)res, ymm3);
```

I thought casting it to double pointer for '`res`' would solve the issue but with no luck..

can anyone please help?

compiler - clang 3.4 - x86 ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[_mm256_store_pd](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/524107) does not return anything. Remove assignment to ymm3:
`_mm256_store_pd((double*)res, ymm3);`

Also you don't need to cast `res` as it is already `double*`

Comment: oh...... how did it ever got in there. thanks!! now it works perfectly. probably need to get some sleep lol.

Comment: That was my first thought when I saw this :) You need to get more sleep :)